# Highcharts Sunburst Select or Drilldown conditionally

Tags: javascript, highcharts, click, drilldown

I am trying to implement Sunburst chart drilldown action conditionally on click event.
Say if am doing a Shift+Click then I would like to change the clicked sector's color. And if I just do a Click then I would like to drilldown or up.
The implemented code works fine, but it works only on the subsequent click/shift+click action, not during the first click.

Here's the [implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/4fbvz5d7/)

Event:
click: function (event) {

```
if (event.shiftKey) {
    chartT.series[0].update({
        allowTraversingTree: false
    });
    this.series.chart.redraw();

    this.color = "blue";

} else {
    chartT.series[0].update({
        allowTraversingTree: true
    });
    this.series.chart.redraw();

    chartT.series[0].data[0].doDrilldown();
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you explain step by step how to reproduce this behavior? _"The implemented code works fine, but it works only on the subsequent click/shift+click action, not during the first click."_

Comment: Hi, 
Steps:
Case 1-Click
1. Open the given Link. 
2. Click on the Sector say 'Asia', its supposed to drill down as per the implementation, but it doesn't. 
3. Click again on Asia, now it will drilldown (2nd click onwards). 
-----
Case 2 - Shift Click
4. Now Shift+click on any sector, it changes the color and also drills down (but expected behavior is-it should only change color and not drilldown). 
5. Do Shift+Click again on any sector - now it changes color and doesn't drill down (expected behavior from 2nd click on). 

Repeat both of the above cases again. 
Thanks!

Comment: I changed the demo and it looks like the solution works, please take a look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pe8szj25/4/).